# Query which should return count value in integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to return count value of various languages in one query using with  and finally it should display total no of count in integer. It should be  combined from different tables in the same Db and finally it should return the total in one query .

Could anyone help me in this .

Thanks

select count(*) from TBL_Count transfer where LANG='Eng'

Comment: Please give some example tables as you are saying you want to count from multiple tables

Comment: @masum7 Hi,I solved this using union to combine both tables

Comment: @hari_cheers then put your answer here for helping others on similar scenario. In case if you really don't need any further help or don't want to provide your solution then delete this post and save others time.